How to prepare JSON payload with dynamic attributes in Power Automate Flow
I'm using two tables 'new_demotable001' and 'new_metadatatable'. One to trigger the flow and another as Mapping Sheet, respectively.
By using both I want to create a JSON payload that I'll use to call external API. Please help me create the payload.
<Details/Prerquisite>

When a new row added in new_demotable001, flow triggers.
The data/attributes we will receive from table are -
Note: I've removed unnecessary attributes.

{
  "new_empname": "EmpName5",
  "new_demotable001id": "259ffaeb-a354-ef11-bfe3-000d3af2cd77",
  "new_empcontact": "555555555555",
  "new_name": "DemoDataTestin",
  "new_empstatus": 100000001,
  "_new_empstatus_label": "On-Boarded"
}


Then fetch details from 'new_metadatatable' table using "List Rows".
The data/attributes we will receive from table are -
Note: I've removed unnecessary attributes.

{
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcount": -1,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcountlimitexceeded": false,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.globalmetadataversion": "10896094",
  "value": [
    {
      "new_sirionattributename": "title",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empname"
      "new_name": "First"
    },
    {
      "new_sirionattributename": "test1",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empcontact",
      "new_name": "Second"
    },
    {
      "new_sirionattributename": "orgId",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empstatus",
      "new_name": "Third"
    }
  ]
}


Now, I want to create a JSON payload using above attributes. To create payload we will use only those attributes which are present in 'new_metadatatable' and also coming from 'new_demotable001'.
-> The Condition I used - contains(triggerOutputs()?['body'], items('Apply_to_each')?['new_dynamicsattributename'])
For above set of data, the expected output payload should be-

{
    "data":{
            "title": "EmpName5",
            "test1": "555555555555",
            "orgId": "100000001"
           }
}



Where does 555555555555 and EmpName5 come from?

@SamNseir, it is coming from the 'new_demotable001'(the trigger). I've corrected that part. :)

In the first Json, are the attributes static? Ie can we hard code new_empname, new_empcontact, and new_empstatus?

@SamNseir, apologies. I didn't get your point. 'new_empname'/'new_empcontact'/'new_empstatus' are attribute names these are hard code names only, we can not change it. But, the number of attributes are not fixed, maybe in future along with these three attributes we start receiving some other attributes like 'new_empsalary' or 'new_empaddress' etc etc.

Try this approach:

Details:
Step: rowDemo
Action: Compose
Comment: you don't need this step, just for demo, this is the first JSON.

Step: metaData
Action: Compose
Comment: you don't need this step, just for demo, this is the second JSON.

Step: selectAttributes
Action: Select
From: outputs('metaData')['value']
Map left: item()?['new_sirionattributename']
Map right: outputs('rowDemo')?[item()?['new_dynamicsattributename']]

Step: payload
Action: Compose
Inputs:
{
  "data": @{json(
replace(
replace(
replace(
  string(body('selectAttributes')),
  '},{', ','), 
  '[', ''), 
  ']', '')
)}
}

Notes:

The selectAttributes step is the key step for mapping the attributes and their values.
The payload step converts the array from the previous step, into a JSON object with string manipulation.

To give you final payload output of:


Boss, you are genius. This is working for me :)
Please let me know if you have youtube channel or blogs, I'd like to follow, as I'm expecting more trouble in this learning journey :P
Highly appreciate if you can guide me.
